# How to convert type 3 fonts to type 1 fonts in eps file?

Tags: image, svg, fonts, inkscape, eps

I created an image in `Microsoft PowerPoint`. Then i used `file -> Save as -> svg` option. Later I imported this `svg` image in `Inkscape` and saved as an `eps` image.

However, it seems like my `eps image` has `type 3` fonts. I want my `eps image` to have `type 1` fonts. Is there a way to prevent inclusion of type 3 fonts in inkscape or powerpoint?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: After you load it into Inkscape, try converting the text to outlines. Then save it as EPS. *Path -> Object to path*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee to be able to convert a type 3 font to a type 1 font. That's because type 3 fonts can contain **anything**.

To be more specific; type 3 fonts can contain colour operators, and images, neither of which is possible in a type 1 font. Type 1 fonts may only contain vector descriptions of the glyph outline.

Without seeing any of the files, it's difficult to be certain, but it's possible that the original .ppt file used pattern fills, Microsoft applications (and, to be fair, other tools) have something of a habit of turning patterns into type 3 fonts. My guess would be that's what is going on. If that's the case then you can't turn the type 3 fonts into type 1.

I'm not an expert on SVG, but I understand that its font support is somewhat limited, and not well supported by SVG consumers. I also don't think it supports type 1 fonts at all.